# How to list total records for all sqlite tables?

Tags: sqlite, sh

I'm using `SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable;` to get the total records of `mytable` but how can I get a list of all tables with their total records ?

```
+--------+-----+
| table1 | 100 |
| table2 | 999 |
| table3 | 500 |
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I guess something like this: `for t in $(sqlite3 db.sqlite '.tables'); do echo $(sqlite3 db.sqlite 'SELECT Count(*) FROM $t') ; done` is closer to what I need, but my syntax for `$t` is wrong.

Comment: `\`echo $t\`` perhaps? (and maybe that would need `"` around the SQL instead of `'`)